# How to refresh a custom kendo grid filter when a cell is changed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My kendo grid uses the Menu filter mode and has a filter applied to one column as follows:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Tech).Width(200).Filterable(f => f.UI("$.proxy(DropDownFilter, { gridName: 'DashboardGrid', field: 'Tech'})").Operators(o => o.ForString(e => e.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to").IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))));
```

The filter itself works fine but when the value of the Tech cell changes I want the filter to update and show the new value of the Tech cell as a filterable option.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: In that case you might need to update the grid datasouce and refresh the filters as well. B'coz Filter itself binded with datasource.

Comment: How do I go about refreshing the filters? I already perform a read when a change is made and the filter is left unaffected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to reset the filters using the following function:

```
function resetFilter() {
     var grid = $("#GridName").getKendoGrid();
     grid.setDataSource(grid.dataSource);
     grid.dataSource.read();
}
```